# How to feather vector mask?

Tags: vector, photoshop-effects, mask

The headline is actual question:) I want to add vector mask to the layer, but I want to soften it's edges because it looks a bit unnatural compared to the rest of the photo, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**apparently you can** https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html#adjust_mask_opacity

when you select the vector mask just open the properties panel—if it's not open already—then you can feather it and adjust opacity.

feathering a raster mask is fine until you decide to resize it ;)

Comment: This is it ! Now I am feeling dumb and happy, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest you can get would be a setup like this:

[image]

Basically create your shape, apply a layer mask to the shape creating the feather how you'd like using whatever tool you want. I did airbrush but could just as easily select your shape, feather it, then make layer mask. Then use it as a clipping mask since it sounds like that's what you're after.

Here it is using the actual shape and feather:

[image]

You'd still have to reapply the Layer Mask each time you adjust the shape but that's not really too difficult and could make an Action to do it if you're using the Feather command instead of the Airbrush.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have on mind! And it's actually simpler than it looks at first sight. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

**You don't**

Feathering vector within Photoshop defeats the purpose of it being vector. If you need a feathered edge, create a raster mask.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I just hope that there is a way to have the best of both worlds: feather within live editable shape :)

Comment: Smart objects would be the only real way in Photoshop (but there's no such animal as a smart object mask that I'm aware of). You could in Illustrator though since you can apply a feather as an effect in Illustrator.

Comment: It would be great if we could have such an option. But as you mentioned, I can use Illustrator. It's no so straightforward, but could solve problem in extreme situation, thanks for the hint !